# Is there a way to change the console code page from within Python?

Tags: python, windows, windows-console, codepages

When I type

> chcp 65001

in the command prompt it changes the active code page. How do I accomplish the same thing from within Python itself? For example, every time I run my .py program, it should automatically change the code page to 65001.

Comment: The console's support for UTF-8 (codepage 65001) is a mess in Windows 7, and even in Windows 10 it limits input to 7-bit ASCII (characters 0-127). Use the console's wide-character API instead. Python 3.6+ already does this for you. In Python 2, install and enable the win_unicode_console package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `chcp` command uses the [`SetConsoleCP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecp) and [`SetConsoleOutputCP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp) Windows API calls to perform its job.  You can invoke those calls directly via [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html):

```python
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes


# helper
def _errcheck_bool(retval, func, args):
    if retval:
        return
    raise ctypes.WinError()


# define SetConsoleCP
SetConsoleCP = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCP
SetConsoleCP.argtypes = (ctypes.wintypes.UINT,)
SetConsoleCP.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL
SetConsoleCP.errcheck = _errcheck_bool


# define SetConsoleOutputCP
SetConsoleOutputCP = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleOutputCP
SetConsoleOutputCP.argtypes = (ctypes.wintypes.UINT,)
SetConsoleOutputCP.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL
SetConsoleOutputCP.errcheck = _errcheck_bool


# invoke
SetConsoleCP(65001)
SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
os.system('chcp 65001')
```

`os.system` lets you send any command to the operating system. So, running this is essentially the same as manually typing `chcp 65001`. See the [docs for os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) for more information.

Comment: Hi! While this may answer the question (untested), it is SO best practice to include why this is a solution to OP's question. It helps OP better understand their problem and benefits future visitors to the site. Please consider adding an explanation to your answer. Thanks! --From Review

Comment: Ok, I added an explanation. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```